# Formatting Help Needed for Math Problem Set in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, formatting, typography

I am seeking some help with formatting a math problem set in LaTeX. The document contains eight problems with sub-problems for each problem, including detailed instructions for solving each problem. The problems involve topics such as linear algebra, trigonometry, chemistry, and electric circuits.

I am having trouble with spacing between each row, margins, and other formatting issues. It doesn't look aesthetically pleasing for me. Could someone please take a look at the code and suggest ways to make it look neater? Your input would be greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{Krysstal 1}
\author{Namn}
\date{April 2023}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section*{Uppgifter}
\subsection*{Uppgift 1}
1. Visa att linjen
$$
x-2=\frac{y+3}{2}=\frac{z-1}{4}
$$
är parallell med planet $2 y-z=1$. Vilket är avståndet mellan linjen och planet?
\subsubsection*{Lösning}
…
\subsection*{Uppgift 2}
2. Punkterna $A=(1,2,3), B=(-2,1,0)$ och $C=(2,0,1)$ bildar en triangel.

(a) Beräkna triangelns area.

(b) Beräkna vinkeln vid punkten $A$.
\subsubsection*{Lösning}
…
\subsection*{Uppgift 3}
3. Vilka av följande utökade systemmatriser är skrivna på trappstegsform och vilka beskriver ett homogent linjärt system? Radreducera de fyra utökade matriserna och markera pivotpositionena. Vilka utökade matriser beskriver ett konsistent system?

$$
A=\left[\begin{array}{llll}
1 & 5 & 4 & 4 \\
3 & 4 & 1 & 6 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 5
\end{array}\right], \quad B=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
5 & -5 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right], \quad C=\left[\begin{array}{lll}
1 & 0 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 2
\end{array}\right], \quad D=\left[\begin{array}{lll}
1 & 3 & 2 \\
3 & 9 & 5
\end{array}\right]
$$
\subsubsection*{Lösning}
…
\subsection*{Uppgift 4}
4. Finn lösningsmängden till ekvationen $A \mathbf{x}=$ b. Finns det noll, en, eller oändligt många lösningar till ekvationen, när

$$
A=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & -2 \\
2 & 2 & -3 \\
1 & 4 & 0
\end{array}\right] \quad \text { och } \quad \mathbf{b}=\left[\begin{array}{l}
0 \\
1 \\
2
\end{array}\right] ?
$$
\subsubsection*{Lösning}
…
\subsection*{Uppgift 5}
5. Förbränning av etanol med väteperoxid ger koldioxid och vatten. Den kemiska formeln kan skrivas

$$
x_{4} \mathrm{C}_{2} \mathrm{H}_{5} \mathrm{OH}+x_{3} \mathrm{H}_{2} \mathrm{O}_{2} \rightarrow x_{2} \mathrm{H}_{2} \mathrm{O}+x_{1} \mathrm{CO}_{2}
$$

Här används koefficienterna $x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}$ och $x_{4}$ för att beskriva antalet molekyler som behövs för att balansera ekvationen, så att det är lika många kol-, väte- och syreatomer i högerledet som i vänsterledet.

Sätt upp ett ekvationssystem bestående av ekvationerna för antalet kol-, väte- och syreatomer i systemet, och lös systemet. Använd de fria variablerna i lösningen till att hitta lägsta möjliga heltal för $x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}$ och $x_{4}$. 
\subsubsection*{Lösning}
…
\subsection*{Uppgift 6}
6. Schemat visar ett resistivt nät med tre resistanser. Ansätt maskströmmar (Lay: loop currents") och ställ upp ekvationssystemet för strömmarna. Lös systemet för fallet $R_{1}=1 \Omega, R_{2}=1 \Omega, R_{3}=2 \Omega, E_{1}=6 \mathrm{~V}$ och $E_{2}=4 \mathrm{~V}$. Beräkna även spänningen över $R_{3}$. Notera att i symbolen för spänningskälla betecknar det längre och smalare strecket pluspolen.
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics{imagee.png}
\end{center}
\subsubsection*{Lösning}
…
\subsection*{Uppgift 7}
7. För vilka värden h är vektorerna $\mathbf{u}=\left[\begin{array}{l}3 \\ 4 \\ 2\end{array}\right] \mathbf{v}=\left[\begin{array}{l}1 \\ 1 \\ 4\end{array}\right]$ och $\mathbf{w}=\left[\begin{array}{l}h \\ 2 \\ 1\end{array}\right]$ linjärt beroende?
\subsubsection*{Lösning}
…
\subsection*{Uppgift 8}
8. En linjär avbildning kan representeras av en matris. Här ska följande matriser användas för att generera avbildningar

$$
A=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0 \\
1 & 1
\end{array}\right], \quad B=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$

(a) Rita en figur som visar hur de två basvektorerna $\mathbf{e}_{x}=\left[\begin{array}{l}1 \\ 0\end{array}\right]$ och $\mathbf{e}_{y}=\left[\begin{array}{l}0 \\ 1\end{array}\right]$ avbildas av matrisen $A$.

(b) Rita en figur som visar hur $\mathbf{e}_{x}$ och $\mathbf{e}_{y}$ avbildas av matrisen $B$.

(c) En sammansatt avbildning kan skapas genom att kombinera två avbildningar. Här ska vi studera den sammansatta avbildning vi får om vi först skapar avbildningen $\mathbf{u} \rightarrow A \mathbf{u} \equiv \mathbf{v}$, och därefter skapar avbildningen $\mathbf{v} \rightarrow B \mathbf{v}=B(A \mathbf{u})$. Rita en figur som visar bilden av den sammansatta avbildningen för $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{e}_{x}$, samt för $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{e}_{y}$.

(d) Vad händer om vi byter ordning på avbildningarna så att $\mathbf{u} \rightarrow A(B \mathbf{u})$ ? Rita en bild för denna sammansatta avbildning när $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{e}_{x}$, samt när $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{e}_{y}$.

(e) Är de två sammansatta avbildningarna $A(B \mathbf{u})$ och $B(A \mathbf{x})$ samma avbildning?
\end{document}
```

Comment: It won't affect the pdf much, but https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/107497.  I would start with looking through the amsmath environments.  Also enumerate, and (babel or polyglossia).  The general idea of LaTeX is that you should be letting LaTeX do as much of the formatting as possible, and you stick to describing what LaTeX is formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I think user Teepeemm gave you the answer already. I could use an itemize environment at the end of your file to get a better math display, or vertically align your matrices in subsection 3, and so on. But if you REALLY WANT to format things manually, you could look at the commands provided by TeX back in the day. For example, `\!` and `\;` gives you predefined white space:

`x-2\!=\!\frac{y+3}{2}\;=\;\frac{z-1}{4}`

`\mkern` gives you a blank space of a given width:

```
2\mkern 30mu y-z=1
```

`\scriptstyle` changes the default font style

```
$${\scriptstyle
A=\left[\begin{array}{llll}
1 & 5 & 4 & 4 \\
3 & 4 & 1 & 6 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 5
\end{array}\right], \quad B=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
5 & -5 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right], \quad C=\left[\begin{array}{lll}
1 & 0 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 2
\end{array}\right], \quad D=\left[\begin{array}{lll}
1 & 3 & 2 \\
3 & 9 & 5
\end{array}\right]}
$$
```

And many more, so you can check them out in your favourite texbook if you're interested. But then again, that comes with a price that LaTeX might not like that too much.

Answer (score 0):

- Your question is very opinion based ...
- Off-topic:

  - `$$` is TeX math delimiter, in LaTeX should be used `\[ ... \]` or `\begin{equation*} ... \end{equation*}`
  - you load `amsmath`, why you not use `bmatrix` for all matrices?
  - chem terms is far more simple to write by employing of `mhchem` package
- for matrices in in-line math you may/should consider to use `bsmallmatrix` or those matrices wrote as display math
- for lists I suggest to use `enumitem` package

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}  % for bsmallmatrix
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{Krysstal 1}
\author{Namn}
\date{April 2023}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section*{Uppgifter}
\subsection*{Uppgift 1}
1. Visa att linjen
\[
x-2=\frac{y+3}{2}=\frac{z-1}{4}
\]
är parallell med planet $2 y-z=1$. Vilket är avståndet mellan linjen och planet?
\subsubsection*{Lösning}
…
\subsection*{Uppgift 2}
2. Punkterna $A=(1,2,3), B=(-2,1,0)$ och $C=(2,0,1)$ bildar en triangel.
    \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item   Beräkna triangelns area.
\item   Beräkna vinkeln vid punkten $A$.
    \end{enumerate}
\subsubsection*{Lösning}
…
\subsection*{Uppgift 3}
3. Vilka av följande utökade systemmatriser är skrivna på trappstegsform och vilka beskriver ett homogent linjärt system? Radreducera de fyra utökade matriserna och markera pivotpositionena. Vilka utökade matriser beskriver ett konsistent system?
\[
A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 5 & 4 & 4 \\
3 & 4 & 1 & 6 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 5
\end{bmatrix}, \quad 
B = \begin{bmatrix}
5 & -5 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}, \quad 
C = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}, \quad 
D = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 2 \\
3 & 9 & 5
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\subsubsection*{Lösning}
…
\subsection*{Uppgift 4}
4. Finn lösningsmängden till ekvationen $A \mathbf{x}=$ b. Finns det noll, en, eller oändligt många lösningar till ekvationen, när
\[
A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -2 \\
2 & 2 & -3 \\
1 & 4 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
    \quad \text{ och }\quad 
\mathbf{b} = \begin{bmatrix}
                0 \\
                1 \\
                2
            \end{bmatrix}
\]
\subsubsection*{Lösning}
…
\subsection*{Uppgift 5}
5. Förbränning av etanol med väteperoxid ger koldioxid och vatten. Den kemiska formeln kan skrivas

\[
x_{4} \ce{C2H5OH}+x_{3} \ce{H2O2} \rightarrow x_{2} \ce{H2O}+x_{1} \ce{CO2}
\]

Här används koefficienterna $x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}$ och $x_{4}$ för att beskriva antalet molekyler som behövs för att balansera ekvationen, så att det är lika många kol-, väte- och syreatomer i högerledet som i vänsterledet.

Sätt upp ett ekvationssystem bestående av ekvationerna för antalet kol-, väte- och syreatomer i systemet, och lös systemet. Använd de fria variablerna i lösningen till att hitta lägsta möjliga heltal för $x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}$ och $x_{4}$.
\subsubsection*{Lösning}
…
\subsection*{Uppgift 6}
6. Schemat visar ett resistivt nät med tre resistanser. Ansätt maskströmmar (Lay: loop currents") och ställ upp ekvationssystemet för strömmarna. Lös systemet för fallet $R_{1}=\qty{1}{\ohm}$, $R_{2}=\qty{1}{\ohm}$, $R_{3}=\qty{2}{\ohm}$, $E_{1}=\qty{6}{\volt}$ och $E_{2}=\qty{4}{\volt}$. Beräkna även spänningen över $R_{3}$. Notera att i symbolen för spänningskälla betecknar det längre och smalare strecket pluspolen.
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics{imagee.png}
\end{center}
\subsubsection*{Lösning}
…
\subsection*{Uppgift 7}
7. För vilka värden h är vektorerna $\mathbf{u}=\begin{bsmallmatrix}3 \\ 4 \\ 2 \end{bsmallmatrix} \mathbf{v}=\begin{bsmallmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 4\end{bsmallmatrix}$ och $\mathbf{w}=\begin{\end{bsmallmatrix}}h \\ 2 \\ 1\end{\end{bsmallmatrix}$ linjärt beroende?

\subsubsection*{Lösning}
…
\subsection*{Uppgift 8}
8. En linjär avbildning kan representeras av en matris. Här ska följande matriser användas för att generera avbildningar
\[
A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}, \quad 
B = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

    \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item   Rita en figur som visar hur de två basvektorerna $\mathbf{e}_{x} = \begin{bsmallmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bsmallmatrix}$ och $\mathbf{e}_{y}=\begin{bsmallmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bsmallmatrix}$ avbildas av matrisen $A$.
\item   Rita en figur som visar hur $\mathbf{e}_{x}$ och $\mathbf{e}_{y}$ avbildas av matrisen $B$.
\item   En sammansatt avbildning kan skapas genom att kombinera två avbildningar. Här ska vi studera den sammansatta avbildning vi får om vi först skapar avbildningen $\mathbf{u} \rightarrow A \mathbf{u} \equiv \mathbf{v}$, och därefter skapar avbildningen $\mathbf{v} \rightarrow B \mathbf{v}=B(A \mathbf{u})$. Rita en figur som visar bilden av den sammansatta avbildningen för $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{e}_{x}$, samt för $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{e}_{y}$.
\item   Vad händer om vi byter ordning på avbildningarna så att $\mathbf{u} \rightarrow A(B \mathbf{u})$ ? Rita en bild för denna sammansatta avbildning när $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{e}_{x}$, samt när $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{e}_{y}$.
\item   Är de två sammansatta avbildningarna $A(B \mathbf{u})$ och $B(A \mathbf{x})$ samma avbildning?
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Compilation above mWE gives three page long document- Last page looks as follows:

[image]